# How to export PowerShell variables from binary modules?

Tags: c#, powershell

You can do that easily from script modules using the `Export-ModuleMember` cmdlet, but how can I do that from binary modules (e.g. C#)?

Comment: Well I posted a whole answer based on misreading your title (though it said cmdlets not variables, somehow). Anyway I don't know if you can for sure, but one way might be to create a small script module that does nothing but export the vairables. In the manifest, the root module could be the script module with a nested module of the DLL. Or vice versa?

Comment: I don’t think it is vice versa. But thanks for taking the time to answer anyway. I ended up creating a pair of set/get cmdlets as an alternative solution.